# Where and when to create a new SQLite database helper?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have an activity which features 2 fragments. Both of them use the database helper created by the activity. One of the fragments also create a custom list adapter which *also* uses the helper.

Now my question is should each of these elements (activity, fragments, adapter) have their own helper created or can/should they share the one created by the activity?

Perhaps my approach is a bad one, what would you suggest then?

Here's where (on my activity) I'm instantiating the helper at the moment (onRestart is needed because onStart needs DB access too) :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    if (dbHelper == null)
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (dbHelper == null)
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dbHelper.close();
    dbHelper = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alex Lockwood recommends using a singleton](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html) - I tried to follow his approach and it simplifies the set up. There is no need to close the DB with each fragment. You can call it in each onCreate.

Comment: Nice link, I've a question though. Should different activities still close the database onPause?

Comment: Initially I tried to include it onDestroy() in all activities but I got run time errors. Right now I only close it onDestroy() in my main activity and nowhere else.